# Как найти и открыть path в windows explorer

Tags: .net, vb.net

Хочу открыть папку в `windows explorer`. Проблема в том, что папка состоит из разных букв и чисел.. в конце же специальный номер, к примеру `_22105510`. Этот номер меняется, но всегда написан в конце названия папки.

Пытался сделать что-то такое.. но путь в таком случае получается "\e\testFolder*22105510", думал `Pattern Options` в `String` поможет..

```
Dim Auftrag as String = "22105510"
Dim OrdnerDatenbearbeitung as String = "\\e\testFolder\"

Try
      Process.Start(OrdnerDatenbearbeitung & "*" & Auftrag)
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нашел такой способ

```
Dim Auftrag as String = "22105510"
Dim OrdnerAuslieferung as String = "\\e\testFolder\"

For Each foundDirectory As String In
       My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories(OrdnerAuslieferung, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*" & Auftrag)
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(foundDirectory) Then
          Process.Start(foundDirectory)
          Exit Sub
        End If
      Next
      MessageBox.Show("Folder not found")
    End If
```